# Working with dynamic MVC Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to develop a view using razor. In this view, i need to add dropdownlist. But the challenge is that there is no specific property for this dropdownlist in my viewmodel. Based on a value(eg:fieldType) from DB in viewmodel, i decide the type of control. Below is the block of code i am using for that.

```
@if (Model.fieldValues[i].FieldType.Equals("TEXT"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fieldValues[i].FieldValue);
}
else if (Model.fieldValues[i].FieldType.Equals("MULTIVALUED"))
{
   @Html.DropDownList(Model.fieldValues[i].OptionFieldValueId.ToString(), Model.fieldValues[i].MultiValueItems)
}
```

I could manage to get the values populated.However, I am not able to get the 'selected value' working for dropdownlist. Also, how do i access this dropdownlist selected value in controller action?

Here are my main viewmodel and submodel.

```
public class ValuesGridViewModel
    {
        public List<CompanyFieldValueViewModel> fieldValues { get; set; }

        public List<int> UniqueBatchIds
        {
            get
            {
                return HelperMethods.GetUniqueValues<int>(fieldValues.Select(x => x.BatchId).ToList());
            }
        }

        public List<string> HeaderList
        {

            get
            {
                return HelperMethods.GetUniqueValues<string>(fieldValues.Select(x => x.Heading).ToList());
            }
        }
    }



  public class CompanyFieldValueViewModel
    {
        public List<MultiValues> MultiValueData { get; set; }
        public int OptionFieldValueId { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string FieldValue { get; set; }
        public string FieldType { get; set; }
        public int? MultiValueId { get; set; }
        public int BatchId { get; set; }

         public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> MultiValueItems
        {
            get
            {
                var list = MultiValueData.Where(x=>x.MultiValueId == this.MultiValueId).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.ValueName,
                    Value = x.ValueId.ToString()
                });
                return list.ToList();
            }

        }

    }
```

new to this site. So, sorry for any formatting issues. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Which property do you want to store the selected value in? Use that as the first parameter for `Html.DropDownListFor`.

As a note, `Model.fieldValues[i].OptionFieldValueId.ToString()` does not return "OptionFieldValueId"; it returns the value of that property, which is probably not what you want.

Try something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fieldValues[i].OptionFieldValueId,
    Model.fieldValues[i].MultiValueItems);
```

Comment: Hi richard, thanks for your answer. I tried DropDownListFor before, but still it couldn't set the selected value for dropdown and renders select element with id "fieldValues[0].OptionFieldValueId", which is not we may expect. I used Dropdownlist helper just to make sure the select element renders with proper, thus by setting selected value. But somehow, that is not working too.

Comment: @Learner99 Never mind, the problem I thought I saw was not a problem. I was assuming that one of the items in `MultiValueItems` would have an ID equal to `OptionFieldValueId`. Is this true?

Comment: Hmm... that's strange that it doesn't select the value, then. I think the ID of "fieldValues[0].OptionFieldValueId" is normal, though (and even necessary).